# How to add JS snippet before closing <head> tag?

Tags: jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I'm setting up jQuery UI on one of my WordPress pages that uses a custom template (course-landing-page.php). I enqueued the scripts for jQuery UI the proper way, but I need to add a JavaScript snippet AFTER the scripts in order to register the tabs on the page.

This is what the code in my functions.php file looks like:

```
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery2', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.10.2', false );

wp_enqueue_script( 'jqueryui', '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.11.4', false );


// Add the jQuery 'tabs' code to pages that use the 'course-landing-page.php' template

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','jQuery_UI_Tabs');
function jQuery_UI_Tabs(){
    if ( is_page_template('course-landing-page.php') ) {
        echo '<script>
                $(function() {
                    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
                });
            </script>';

    }
```

It works great, EXCEPT for the fact that the JavaScript snippet is displaying BEFORE the enqueued jQuery UI scripts, and therefore it's causing the tabs not to work properly. How can I make it so the snippet shows up AFTER the enqueued scripts in the header?

Comment: You should place this in it's own javascript file, then use the third parameter of [wp_enqueue_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to set the dependencies that this new javascript file depends on

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) function and the dependency parameter to ensure scripts are loaded in the appropriate order, and if you're adamant in using inline scripts, you can add it with the [`wp_add_inline_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/) function.

Also, WordPress has jQuery already installed, so you don't have to enqueue them on the frontend, simply list them as dependencies for your script and they'll get loaded before yours.

```
function jQuery_UI_Tabs() {

    if ( is_page_template('course-landing-page.php' ) ) {

        // Enqueue your script with dependencies
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'myTabs', // Handle
            '', // Absolute URL to the script, but yours is inline so empty
            array(
                'jquery', // Dependent on jQuery
                'jquery-ui-tabs' // Dependent on jQuery UI Tabs
            ), // Dependencies
            false, // Version
            false // Put in header
        );
        wp_add_inline_script(
            'myTabs', // Handle,
            'var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); $(function() { $( "#tabs" ).tabs(); });' // Your inline JavaScript
        );

    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','jQuery_UI_Tabs');
```

However, should you want to use CDN versions of jQuery instead, you absolutely can, just enqueue those and list those as your script's dependencies.

I also would recommend putting this particular JavaScript in it's own script file instead of inline and loading it in the footer for performance reasons, but I wanted to answer this particular case.

Comment: Seriously, I need to start checking the dates of these questions. I don't know why questions that are "modified today" are like... pretending they've been asked today, so I go in answering thinking it's a new question lol

Comment: Ha I have been tricked the same way recently.  It seems a bot is pinging them and brings them back to the top. Good answer anyways ;)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, solved it with this!

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'jQuery_UI_Tabs' );
function jQuery_UI_Tabs() {
if ( is_page_template('course-landing-page.php' ) ) {
    echo'<script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
            });
        </script>';
}
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. You can use the parameters of wp_enqueue_script to set the dependency and also there is a flag to load it in the footer.

Comment: Or, just add it directly inside the template, where you want it to be - no need for all this complexity..

Comment: To ensure your action runs later than the others, you can also set the third parameter to something higher than 10 like this: `add_action( 'wp_head', 'jQuery_UI_Tabs', 20);`